# Quotient as the domain of the general linear group.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I have been given the following to work with

\begin{align*}
  GL_{2} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}
and I am not sure what it means. I would think that it means
\begin{align*}
  GL_{2} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=\left(\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a+2\mathbb{Z}  & b+2\mathbb{Z}   \\
    c+2\mathbb{Z}      & d+2\mathbb{Z}    
  \end{pmatrix} :a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z} \quad   \det \neq 0
   \right\},+ \right)
\end{align*}
where the elemens of the matrix are cosets. However, I am having trouble with the condition that $ \det \neq 0 $ . What does this exactly mean this context? Clearly
\begin{align*}
  \det \begin{pmatrix} a+2\mathbb{Z}  & b+2\mathbb{Z}   \\
    c+2\mathbb{Z}      & d+2\mathbb{Z}    
  \end{pmatrix} =(a+2\mathbb{Z})(d+2\mathbb{Z})-(b+2\mathbb{Z})(c+2\mathbb{Z}),
\end{align*}
however how do I interpret these products of cosets? Is it
\begin{align*}
  \det \begin{pmatrix} a+2\mathbb{Z}  & b+2\mathbb{Z}   \\
    c+2\mathbb{Z}      & d+2\mathbb{Z}    
  \end{pmatrix} =(a+2\mathbb{Z})(d+2\mathbb{Z})-(b+2\mathbb{Z})(c+2\mathbb{Z})& =ad-bc+(a+d-b-c)2\mathbb{Z}+2\mathbb{Z}-2\mathbb{Z} \\ 
  & =ad-bc+(a+d-b-c \;\text{mod 2}\;)2\mathbb{Z}  ?
\end{align*}
If yes, then I am a bit confused how we are going from algebraic multiplication, that is the standard definition of determinant for numbers,  to that of coset multication combined algebraic multiplication. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is understood to be a ring; in particular, a field. We define

$$(x+2\Bbb Z)(y+2\Bbb Z)=xy+2\Bbb Z$$

for integers $x,y$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is used for the field with two elements, $0$ and $1$, where the sum and the product are made modulo $2$ (for particular, in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ you have $1+1=0$).